# Python Turtle AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'position'

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, swampy

I have the following code to play with turtle within `turtleworld`:

```
>>> from swampy.TurtleWorld import *
>>> world = TurtleWorld()
>>> bob = Turtle()
>>> fd(bob, 100)
>>> bob.position()
>>> bob.reset()
```

There is no issue with executing the `fd(bob, 100)` line but when I try to check turtle position it returns `AttributeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    bob.position()
AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'position'
```

Why is this happening? What am I missing? I have read the documentation and it states that both `position()` and `reset()` methods should be available.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, but it looks like there is no such attribute indeed: https://github.com/AllenDowney/Swampy/blob/master/python3/TurtleWorld.py#L102

Comment: Thank you. As stated below by HKJeffer I have mixed `turtle` module with `swampy.TurtleWorld`'s `Turtle` class. Thank you for the link, I need to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be mixing up the `turtle` module with `swampy.TurtleWorld`'s `Turtle` class.

In the [`turtle` module](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.position), there is indeed a `position()` method, however there isn't in [`swampy.TurtleWorld`'s `Turtle` class](https://github.com/AllenDowney/Swampy/blob/master/python3/TurtleWorld.py#L102), as mentioned by @Georgy in the comments.

You can instead use `bob.get_x()` and `bob.get_y()` for its x, y coordinates.

Comment: Thank you, I just got lost at the beginning of my adventure with Python. It seems too many turtles around ;)